# ExtJS Loading Link List Tree Using Ajax

Tags: extjs

I have the below code that I am trying to get the list of dates using Ajax and display those on the page as links to elsewhere.  So each entry would be a link that when you click would take you elsewhere. Though the treelist is not loading any items...

Data

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    "2018-10-08T00:00:00",
    "2018-10-05T00:00:00",
    "2018-10-04T00:00:00",
    "2018-10-03T00:00:00",
  ]
}
```

Code

```
Ext.define('...', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: '...',

    requires: [
        '...'
    ],

    layout: 'border',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        store: {
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '...',
                useDefaultXhrHeader: true,
                withCredentials: true,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                },
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: You should use `rootProperty: 'data'` as per your JSON.

Comment: Even using that doesn't work... I just updated the code now...

Comment: Can you please post working fiddle so that it will be easy to track your problem

Comment: I am using a whole application of so many files/folders. I don't know how to translate that into a fiddle removing certain areas. I'll update my code to display the page I am working on. This is the whole page I have. I am trying to pull list of text using ajax onto this page.

Comment: Let us look at your treelist component, you can copy just a fragment without other project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display a grid with your data. It can show clickable links.

To do this you need to make a grid with your ajax store and a grid renderer like this:

```
 // Ajax store

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
           storeId: 'mystore',
           autoLoad: true,
           proxy: {
               type   : 'ajax',
               url    : '/file.php',
               actionMethods: {
                   read: 'POST'
               },
               reader : {
                   type: 'json'
               },
               extraParams : {
                   key       : 'val'
               },
               fields  : [
                   {name: 'date',  type: 'string'}
               ]
           }
       })


 // Grid

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            scrollable: true,
            store: {
                type: 'mystore'
            },
            columns: [
            {
                text: 'link column',
                dataIndex:'link',
                renderer: function(value) {
                        if(value) {
                            // here you can format your output
                            return '<a href="'+value+'">'+value+'</a>';
                        }
                    }

            }
            ]
        })
```

Please [look whole example in a Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mg6)